# Is it possible to have a modal in a tab and hide when selecting another tab?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, modal-dialog

My application uses a tab display to show different records.  On each tab, we have actions (buttons) that can open a modal to display more detail information and allow for editing.  Primarily the child record in a master/child relationship (e.g., an address of a contact record).

We would like the "modal" to be within the tab so that a user can switch between tabs while the modal is shown; and hidden when a different the tab is selected/active.  The modal would be re-displayed when the user comes back to the tab.

I've started to research this and would appreciate any ideas for how this can be accomplished.  I figure I'm going to have to create my own web component that mimics a modal and able to be contained within a tab.

We are using angular 8.0 if that makes any difference.

Thanks,
Chris...

Answer (score 0):

If it's supposed to be within tab why not implement it as a normal component which appears  on a button click event? You can create an overlay with a simple flex container with absolute positioning which covers tab body and aligns modal component to the center of the tab. You can control it with an ngIf or by hiding with css if you want it rendered all the time in background.

Since that overlay/component is a part of a tab it can be displayed only when that certain tab is opened.

If you have multiple different modals to load, you can solve that by using ngSwitch or by dynamically loading modal component.